# How to copy a string into a new dynamically allocated string in 64-bit ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm64

How would I dynamically allocate the data in the program below instead of statically. At least from what I've heard, you need to follow 3 steps...

1. Malloc the static string
2. Get the length of the string and pass it to malloc
3. Copy the string into the new malloc'd string. (?)

How would I accomplish step 3? Here's what I have so far...

```
.data 

str1:   .asciz "The Cat in the Hat\n"

data:   .quad 0

.global _start

.text

_start:

    // Static Version

    LDR X0,=str1;   // Points to the string "Cat in the Hat\n" 

    LDR X1,=data;   // Points to "Data"
    STR X0,[X1].    // Stores the string into "Data"


    // Dynamic Version: What I have so far...
    
    LDR X0,=str1;   // Points to the string "Cat in the Hat\n" 

    BL  strlength   // Returns the length of the string in X0. Modifies registers 
                    // X0, X1, X2, and X7 
    ADD X0,X0,#1    // +1 to the length to account for the null at the end 
    BL  malloc      // Passes X0 into malloc as the amount of bytes to be dynamically 
                    // allocated. Returns the Address of the block of memory allocated 
                    // in X0

    LDR X1,=str1    // Holds the string 

loop:

    LDRB    W5,[X1],#1  // Grabs the first byte from the string
    STRB    W5,[X0],#1  // Stores that byte into X0

    CMP     W5, #0      // Checks for Null
    B.EQ    endLoop     // Branches if Null
    
    B       loop        // Loops
    

    endLoop:       
          
                                        


    LDR X1,=data;   // Points to "Data"
    STR X0,[X1].    // Stores the string into "Data"


end:
    MOV X0, #0
    MOV X8, #93
    SVC 0
```

Comment: Do you know how to copy one byte?  Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: Save the length in a register that `malloc` won't destroy (i.e. a call-preserved register), then call memcpy or implement it yourself.

Comment: Also, your "step 1" isn't a real thing.  You can't "malloc the static string", malloc takes a length, not a string.  If you mean reserving static storage space for it in `.data`, that's not malloc, and isn't part of the duplicating a string, it's just a test input for the function.  BTW, glibc includes a `strdup` function that does this for you.  It's part of POSIX 2001, so you could just call it, unless you're specifically limiting yourself only to `malloc` as the only real libc function, not also `strlen`.  I notice you `bl strlength` but don't define that custom function.